# Email going into spam in php using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer to send email with pdf attachment but it's going in spam. My email is simple with just pdf attachment. I've tried everything on google but don't know I'm missing. Following is my code.

```
 $email_settings = ORMEmailSettings::order_by('id', 'desc')->limit(1)->first();
    $email_host = $email_settings->email_host;
    $email_username = $email_settings->email_username;
    $email_password = $email_settings->email_password;

    require_once APPPATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'controllers/admin/smtp/class.phpmailer.php';
    if ($eventTicketId != 9999) {
        $eventId = $this->events_model->getAttachment($eventTicketId[0]->event_id);
        $emailSubject = $eventId[0]->title;
    } else {
        $emailSubject = "Here come the normal subject";
    }
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = 'true';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->Host = 'xxxx.xxmsrv.de';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Username = "xxxxxxx@myplusmarketing.com";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx2014*";
    $mail->SingleTo = true;

    $mail->From = "xxxxxxxxxxx@myplusmarketing.com";
    $mail->FromName = "My Email";
    $mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxxx.de');
    if ($eventTicketId != 9999) {
        $filename = "MPM-event" . $eventId[0]->id . "_.pdf";
        $filelocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/eventDocs';
        $fileNL = $filelocation . "/" . $filename;
        $mail->AddAttachment($fileNL, $filename,  $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
    }
    $mail->Subject = $emailSubject;
    $mail->Body = '<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;     line-height: 17px;">
</body>
</html>';

    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo 'if';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo 'else';
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: `$mail->SMTPAuth = 'true';` should be `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;` and you don't need to set `SingleTo` as you're only sending to one address anyway. It looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're running latest PHPMailer.

Answer (score 3):

Your message going into spam doesn't mean your code is failing – on the contrary, it clearly works! The problem is that the receiving server doesn't trust your site, so it flags the incoming email as spam so end users never see it.

The solution is probably not code-based. Instead, you should look to add an SPF record for your domain. This isn't hard to do as long as you have a helpful web host. If it's your first time doing this, you should consider using something like http://www.spfwizard.net, which does all the hard work for you.

Comment: as you have seen in my question, I'm sending pdf as attachment, i've just found that if i do not send attachment then it goes to inbox but when attachment is their it's going into spam.

Comment: Again, that doesn't mean your code isn't working, it just means the server thinks your attachment is fishy. Try SPF and I believe it will be cleared up.

Comment: I'd recommend the definitive http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html for creating and testing your SPF.